# What would cause spontaneous default network changes and how to fix smb access?

Tags: networking, samba, routing

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop install with 4x physical network interfaces. One interface connects to a larger network with access to file shares etc and the others connect to smaller networks to control hardware interfaces (robot controllers etc).  I had a smb share mounted fine, had restarted the machine several times and all was working fine, but all of a sudden it looks like the default network has changed so and subnet resolution is no longer working.  ie if I try to ping the smb server it says cannot connect, but if I specify the network interface using -I then ping works.  AFAIK nothing else has changed on the computer, it's not even connected to the internet so can't pull updates etc.

1. What could cause this change to happen?
2. The different networks have different subnets, shouldn't Ubuntu resolve this?
3. How can I specify a subnet or network controller when mounting a smb share?

Comment: You mention a Ubuntu release (20.04) but not which product (ie. are you using Desktop which uses *NetworkManager* or Server using *Netplan*).  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was also a LTS release, thus initial defaults are set by installation media used (Server & Desktop ISOs had different defaults).

Comment: Updated the question,  its 20.04 LTS Desktop